# Creating a 2D array on construction with a variable length

Tags: c++, arrays

How can a setup a class that I can have a private 2D array that's size is determined by the variables passed in via the constructor?

I've tried this:

```
class World {
    private:
        const int WIDTH;
        const int HEIGHT;
        bool map[][];
    public:
        World(const int MAX_X, const int MAX_Y) : WIDTH(MAX_X), HEIGHT(MAX_Y) {
            map = new bool[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
        }
};
```

But I get a bunch of errors about how `declaration of ‘map’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first` and `array size in operator new must be constant` even though it is.

I've also tried it this way but it didn't work either:

```
class World {
    private:
        const int WIDTH;
        const int HEIGHT;
        bool map[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    public:
        World(const int MAX_X, const int MAX_Y) : WIDTH(MAX_X), HEIGHT(MAX_Y) {
            //map = new bool[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
        }
};
```

I get a `invalid use of non-static data member ‘World::WIDTH’` on the `const int WIDTH` line and a quite useless `error: from this location` on the map declaration line.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
I'd prefer to avoid using vectors since I haven't "learned" them yet in this class. (by learned I mean I know how to use them but the professor hasn't discussed them and doesn't like us using outside knowledge)

Comment: Suggestion -- Do not name your variable `map`.

Comment: C-style arrays are very picky which is why we advise people not to use them. If width and height are truly known at compile-time, the arrays can be made to work.

Comment: Why shouldn't I name it map? And dimensions are known at construction and not before.

Comment: In C++ array sizes must be known at compile-time. If you don't know it before then you cannot use a C-style array, end of story. The `vector` class provides the functionality that "array" does in every other language that has arrays.

Comment: Even if runtime array size were permitted, class sizes still have to be known at compile-time so you could not use one as a class member .

Comment: Because of confusion with `std::map` data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a vector.

```
class World
{
   typedef std::vector<bool> Tiles;
   typedef std::vector<Tiles> WorldMap;

   World(unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
   {
     for (unsigned int i = 0; i < width; i++)
     {
         m_map.push_back(Tiles(height));
     }
   }

private:
   WorldMap m_map;      
};
```

Or you could use templates, if you know the world size at compile time.

```
template <unsigned int Width, unsigned int Height>
class World
{
private:
  bool m_map[Width][Height];
};
```

Or you could use raw pointers, since a 2d array is really just an array of pointers to arrays.

```
class World
{
   // Make sure you free this memory.
   World(unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
   {
     m_map = new bool*[width];
     for(unsigned int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
     {
        m_map[i] = new bool[width];
     }
   }

private:
   bool** m_map;
};
```

I suggest using one of the first two options.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays must have their sizes determined at compile-time, not run time.

You should choose a different container if you want run-time sizing.  Possibly:

```
 - std::vector<bool>  // and then simulate a 2d array using indexing 
 - std::vector<std::vector<bool>> // if you insist on using [][] syntax
```

Comment: To clarify by indexing, `[x + y * x_size]` to get the index.

Comment: I've already done the "simulate a 2d array using indexing" with a standard array, but I'd prefer to do it the "right way" and use an actual 2d array. I'm puzzled at C++'s exclusion of runtime determined sizes for arrays

Comment: @Malfist - The issue is that declaring arrays the way you did requires allocation of memory on the stack with a size provided at compile time. C++ doesn't 'exclude' the ability to have 2d arrays built at runtime, you just need to do it different way.